# Newly created web template is invisible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-template

I have created a new web template (contains a elements.xml and onet.xml) which is based on team site. I have deployed the .wsp file. However when I go to "New Site" under Site Actions I cannot see my web template. I know that it has been deployed because I was able to successfully create a new site based on this new created web template by using Powershell. Also when I recreate the site collections it appears. is there any solution to make the web template be visible without recreate the site collections?

I am using SharePoint 2010 if that can matter.

Comment: Propably hidden. Get into Powershell and do a Get-SPWebTemplates. Find youd template and check the visibility.

Comment: I dont think it is hidden because if it is hidden then it shouldn't be appear on the other site collection. it is my developing environment, when I installed sp2010 it created http://dev web application on my "Default web site". all web templates I created are visible there but not visible on my other web application.